# R data frame create new column from first existing column or NA if no existing columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, rlang

The following function return first existing column in data frame, or `NA` if no existing columns

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.2.3

# `dplyr::coalesce` return fist non-missing, but these columns must exist

return_exist_var <- function(.var1, .var2, .fill = NA, .data) {
  # get the . from magrittr::%>%
  .data <- get(".", parent.frame())
  stopifnot(is.data.frame(.data))
  .var1 <- rlang::enexpr(.var1)
  .var2 <- rlang::enexpr(.var2)
  if (rlang::as_string(.var1) %in% names(.data)) {
    return(rlang::parse_expr(rlang::as_string(.var1)))
  } else if (rlang::as_string(.var2) %in% names(.data)) {
    return(rlang::parse_expr(rlang::as_string(.var2)))
  } else {
    return(.fill)
  }
}

df <- data.frame(
  ID = c("ID01", "ID01", "ID02", "ID02"),
  v1 = c("a", "b", "c", NA),
  v2 = c("A", "B", "C", "C")
)
```

### return first existing column

```r
df %>% dplyr::mutate(NEW = !!return_exist_var(v1))
#>     ID   v1 v2  NEW
#> 1 ID01    a  A    a
#> 2 ID01    b  B    b
#> 3 ID02    c  C    c
#> 4 ID02 <NA>  C <NA>
```

### return first existing column in two column

```r
df %>% dplyr::mutate(NEW = !!return_exist_var(v2, v1))
#>     ID   v1 v2 NEW
#> 1 ID01    a  A   A
#> 2 ID01    b  B   B
#> 3 ID02    c  C   C
#> 4 ID02 <NA>  C   C
```

### return second existing column in two column

```r
df %>% dplyr::mutate(NEW = !!return_exist_var(v1_x, v2))
#>     ID   v1 v2 NEW
#> 1 ID01    a  A   A
#> 2 ID01    b  B   B
#> 3 ID02    c  C   C
#> 4 ID02 <NA>  C   C
```

### return NA if two column not eixst

```r
df %>% dplyr::mutate(NEW = !!return_exist_var(v1_X, v2_X))
#>     ID   v1 v2 NEW
#> 1 ID01    a  A  NA
#> 2 ID01    b  B  NA
#> 3 ID02    c  C  NA
#> 4 ID02 <NA>  C  NA
```

### work well on grouped data frame

```r
df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(ID) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(NEW = !!return_exist_var(v1))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>   ID    v1    v2    NEW  
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 ID01  a     A     a    
#> 2 ID01  b     B     b    
#> 3 ID02  c     C     c    
#> 4 ID02  <NA>  C     <NA>
```

## Problem

How to update the function, then call function like below without `!!`, or define a new same function

`df %>% dplyr::mutate(NEW = return_exist_var(v1))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified version of your function that relies on using `any_of()` to handle missing vars.  As `any_of()` requires a character vector, the arguments need to be deparsed before use.

```
library(dplyr)

return_exist_var <- function(...) {
  var_list <-  match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
  c(pick(any_of(sapply(var_list, deparse))), NA)[[1]]
  }

df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(NEW = return_exist_var(v1))

    ID   v1 v2  NEW
1 ID01    a  A    a
2 ID01    b  B    b
3 ID02    c  C    c
4 ID02 <NA>  C <NA>

df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(NEW = return_exist_var(v2, v1))

    ID   v1 v2 NEW
1 ID01    a  A   A
2 ID01    b  B   B
3 ID02    c  C   C
4 ID02 <NA>  C   C

df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(NEW = return_exist_var(v1_x, v2))

    ID   v1 v2 NEW
1 ID01    a  A   A
2 ID01    b  B   B
3 ID02    c  C   C
4 ID02 <NA>  C   C

df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(NEW = return_exist_var(v1_X, v2_X))

    ID   v1 v2 NEW
1 ID01    a  A  NA
2 ID01    b  B  NA
3 ID02    c  C  NA
4 ID02 <NA>  C  NA

# Works if data is grouped
df %>%
  mutate(NEW = return_exist_var(v1), .by = ID)

    ID   v1 v2  NEW
1 ID01    a  A    a
2 ID01    b  B    b
3 ID02    c  C    c
4 ID02 <NA>  C <NA>
```

Comment: For `df %>% dplyr::mutate(NEW = return_exist_var(v1, v2))`, if the result of row num 4 can be just value  of `v1` , that is not first non missing of `v1` and `v2`

Comment: @bgxq - I see, I thought you wanted to coalesce the values but it's an easy fix.  See edit.